# What happens when multiple scripts write in the same google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have set up a database in google sheet and I am using a few web apps to collect inputs and manipulate data. As the number of users growth, I am wondering what happen when 2 or more scripts try to write in the sheet at the same time.

For example, let's say Script A takes the data in a sheet, put it in an array, modify the array, and then write back to the sheet the new array (few rows added, few deleted).

Script B is triggered while script A still running and wants to perform similar operations. Script A and Script B are different Google scripts but operates in the same Sheet and same tab.

Is there a mechanism which create a queue for Script B in the example above?

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To control how scripts edit a sheet, you should use [LockService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock)

This allows a script to

- check if there is curretly lock
- If there already is a lock, wait for the specified amount of time for the script that imposed the lock to release this one again
- Once there is on lock anymore- the current script can acquire a lock
- It will release the lock after finishing execution, so that other scripts can execute

Sample

```js
function lock() {
// Get a script lock, because we're about to modify a shared resource.
lock.tryLock(10000);
if (!lock.hasLock()) {
  Logger.log('Could not obtain lock after 10 seconds.');
}else{
  Logger.log("I am the script who has the lock now");
  // Release the lock so that other processes can continue.
  lock.releaseLock();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. This help to prevent that Script A is run by multiple users at the same time on the same document. However, I am not sure if it helps when 2 different scripts (2 different google script projects with different code) run at the same time and edit the same document?

Comment: The script lock works only when different users access the same script. But there is also a DocumentLock and a UserLock - see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service#getDocumentLock()). Also, consider making a "common script" from where all other scripts will be called when required.